# Installing app as update from xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

The Apple App Store rejected my app for an error that I'm having trouble reproducing (a button was unresponsive). I'm updating an existing app, and their suggestion to reproduce the issue is "For updates, install the new version as an update to the previous version, then follow the steps to reproduce the issue".

How do you install the app as an update to an existing version from Xcode? Is there a way to do this through ITunes or ITunes Conect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete any version of the app from your device then install the current version from the App Store just like any user would.

Then use Xcode to install your development build of your update. This will overwrite the App Store version in a matter very similar to a user performing a normal update of an app. Then figure out why your updated app isn't working in this situation.